Can not load offline map tiles in Qml without internet access
I want to bring up an offline map using QtLocation in Qml. I have found the code in this blog post. The problem is that in order to load the tiles I should first connect to internet and without that tiles are not loading.
main.qml :
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtLocation 5.8

Window {
    id: win
    objectName: "window"
    visible: true
    width: 512
    height: 512

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        activeMapType: map.supportedMapTypes[1]
        zoomLevel: 1
        plugin: Plugin {
            name: 'osm';
            PluginParameter {
                name: 'osm.mapping.offline.directory'
                value: ':/offline_tiles/'
            }
        }
    }
}

I don't get any warning or error running the code.
I'm using Qt 5.12.3

Have you tried the example provided in that blog post? https://qt-blog-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/OsmOffline.zip

@Pa_ Yes, this is exactly the same code that I linked to in the question. It needs to be connected to the internet to load offline tiles. I am looking for a method that does not require the Internet connection.

That is odd, because I tried that project, and it worked alright. But it could be that, the first time i ran it, i was online. Or simply i ran some qtlocation application before. The OSM plugin, by default, needs to download init files from the network, that you can disable or provide yourself. check  https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/03/09/provisioning-openstreetmap-providers-in-qtlocation for details

@Pa_ Thank you for the information. finally I fixed it using this solution
